# Image in avatar of MUI is displayed rotated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, material-ui

everyone. I wonder why my avatar is displayed rotated. I'm using the Map element from Material Design with React. Can I always display the image "correctly"? Thanks

[image]

Main Part of code:

```
<Card>
  <CardHeader
    avatar={
      <Avatar
        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/image.JPG"}
        alt="Masterman"
      ></Avatar>
    }

  ....
</Card>
```

Comment: show your front-end code so, we can check it out

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox with your code and the image that replicates the issue so we can understand what is happening? Thanks

Comment: maybe the problem with your image.JPG check that image is straight  in this path process.env.PUBLIC_URL